# Integration in physical forms

Tags: calculus

Suppose we have a straight uniform rod and we divide it into infinitesimal sections.The total mass of the rod is $M$.Now each section has mass $dM$.Then the total mass in integration form is given by $\int_{0}^{M}dM$.My question is what do we mean by the limits $0$ and $M$ on the integration sign.If it was length $dx$ instead of mass,then $\int_{0}^{x}dx$ would have made sense to me since we are slicing from the top to bottom in length but i don't get it how $0$ and $M$ plays the role of top to bottom in this case.

Comment: Does it help to think of the integral as the integral of M(x) dx?

Comment: @eSurfsnake I think you mean $\int M^\color{red}{\prime}(x)dx$.

Comment: Neither of your comments answered my question

Comment: Nor, apparently, did my answer. In that case, I don't think either of us knows what your question is. Perhaps you don't either. Isn't the onus on you to explain why $M=\int_0^Mdu$ is so much less intuitive than $x=\int_0^xdu$? Why would mathematics care whether it's a length or mass?

Answer (score 1):

It should be $M=\int_0^MdM^\prime$ vs. $x=\int_0^xdx^\prime$. If you seek a physical interpretation, imagine the gradual addition of small amounts of mass.

Comment: I know about adding but what do we mean by the limits 0 and M?It's not like we are adding from 0 to M.

Comment: @AritraBarua Sure we are. Imagine grating a certain mass of cheese onto a plate. The size or shape of each shaving isn't what we care about here.

Comment: Sorry but i don't think that answers my question